# PHP SQL Array looping

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, while-loop

I've been using a fair bit of PHP lately, and whilst I've generally found it quite fun and fairly painless, I'm worried I might have stumbled upon one of the quirks so many people seem to hate it for.

Consider this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    //Do something with $row...
}
```

...where $result is a mysql_query like:

> SELECT name, age FROM people

Each time the loop executes, $row refers to a different row in the results returned.

I've never known a language where the while(... statement does anything other than execute if the condition it checks is true, and I can see how the above would do the same...but I can't see how a while loop causes it to *iterate* over the indices of the array fetched.

Is this simply a bizarre quirk of PHP, or does the object returned by mysql_fetch_array increment/splice itself every time it's referenced?

I understand how it works, so I can use it in my code, but I don't understand *why* and I don't like rote-coding - if anyone could explain I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Please switch to MySQLi or PDO. These methods have been depreciated. :) [See PHP Page on mysql functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: Ah ok, I had to figure out SQL with PHP from scratch and all the tuts I found used the mysql_ methods. I'll give PDO a go, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the object returned by mysql_fetch_array increment/splice itself every time it's referenced

You are right on the money. For some reason it doesn't say so in the manual reference for this specific function, but let's take a look at the reference for the very similar `mysql_fetch_row`
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Quoting from the reference:

> Returns a numerical array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

After the internal data pointer moves ahead, calling this function once again will fetch the next row. This behavior has nothing to do with the `while` itself. You can also call the function multiple times in consecutive lines.

This sort of behavior is actually quite common. Consider reading from files with API similar to `fread`. Every time you read, you receive the next chunk of data. This is also implemented using an internal data pointer, also known as a cursor.

Comment: Ah of course! I've used ByteArrays in AS3 a fair bit before, I should have figured it worked in the same way but couldn't find much info about it, guess the 'while' loop makes sense now but it misled me - thanks a lot!

Comment: I like php, but personally think that having an assignment inside the while statement is disgusting :) you can easily rewrite to avoid it though and make the code a bit more readable